# Extracting a specific href from table

Tags: python, href

I'm trying to extract the "10-K" url and append it into a list from the following site:

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000091205701544436/0000912057-01-544436-index.htm

Picture 1
[image: my code]

So basically I'm trying to extract the first  under the first  that does not have  as its sub category.

Am trying to create a loop to loop this code in multiple similar-like links, but guess I'm trying to resolve this issue first for now.

Any ideas?

Comment: `I'm trying to extract the first under the first that does not have as its sub category.` => Still not clear your expected result. Could you provide your current working and what stuck you got?

Comment: if you want to extract href tag from the source, user beautifulsoup4 package.
https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answers your requirement.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000091205701544436/0000912057-01-544436-index.htm"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

rows = soup.findAll("td")

href_list = []
for ele in rows:
    a_Tag = ele.findChildren("a")
    if a_Tag:
        href_list.append(a_Tag)

print(href_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you'r quastion but if I got i rigth this can help you

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000091205701544436/0000912057-01-544436-index.htm")

s = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
print(s.find("table").findChild("a")["href"])
```